# Settings default values to a listbox in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application.

I have a userControl "MycustomControl" that contains a dependencyProperty which is a list of images.

In one of the windows I MycustomControl ~4 times, and in all of them I need to initialize the list to the same list of images.

I tried to do it using style. something like that:

```
  <Style TargetType="MycustomControl">
            <Setter Property="Imeages" >
                <Image Source="1.png"></Image>
                <Image Source="2.png"></Image>
                <Image Source="3.png"></Image>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: My spider senses tell me that you're doing it all wrong and that you don't need a Custom Control for what you're doing, and that UI is not data, and you should place Data in Data Items, not UI Elements.

Comment: I completely agree with you :) the problem is that I must do it this way because someone else had created the infrastructure, and I don't want to touch or change anything....